# Can I take the credit card of my father to Portugal?

Tags: car-rentals, payment-cards, portugal

I'll travel to Portugal soon, I'm going to rent a car in Lisbon. This rental car agency ask for a credit card to rent a car.

I live in Switzerland. I'm a student and I can't get a credit card in my country because I don't have a monthly salary of 2000 CHF.

So my question is : can I take the credit card of my father to rent the car ?

If no, how can I rent the car ?
If yes, can I might have problem at the airport ?

Comment: Two obvious questions: 1) What type of credit card (and does the bank issue any fee or have any limitation or rules on use abroad), 2) Have you asked your father? He'll probably need to inform the bank that it'll be used abroad (some banks assume unexpected use overseas is fraud and block the card)

Comment: It's a common Mastercard , no special rule abroad. You still have a spend limit. Yes I asked my father to use his card.

Comment: Why not get a prepaid credit card?

Comment: I already have a prepaid credit card but I asked my bank and they said that you can't rent a car with it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The rental desk often wishes to see that the credit card is issued in exactly the same name as the driving licence. If you and your father share a name or a first initial it would probably be acceptable, but it seems to me a bit risky.

A better solution is to ask your father to take out a second card on the same account, but in your name. This is called a "supplementary card". He will be liable for any spending that you do, but the card will be in your name.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I didn't know that you could create a credit card in the name of someone linked with your account.

Comment: It's almost always called a `supplementary credit card`, not all providers offer them though

Comment: @Cytriq generally Supplementary Cards share the limit with their Main/Parent card. Main card holder is responsible for all spendings n payments. Also, in some banks, main card holder could define a maximum limit for child/supplementary cards.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, yes you can!

The only way is if you and your dad share the same name. I have used my Dad's credit card multiple times while using my own ID/DL. There is no way for the rental car company to know the exact details of the bank account. I know from experience, and have done it more than once.

Comment: I do not know about Portugal, but in Poland it is a crime to use another person's credit card. So your answer should not be as simple as that.